# Check if matrix is square

Tags: python

Hey I’m new to python just wanted to know and I’m doing this correct before I submit it?

```
inverse = []
matrix = [[1, 2] , [3, 4]]
if len (matrix) != len(matrix [0]):
raised (‘The matrix must be square’)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to raise an error type and change your logic for determining if the matrix is square:

```
inverse = []
matrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
if len(matrix) != len(matrix[0]) and len(set(map(len, matrix))) != 1:
   raise AttributeError('The matrix must be square') #or error of your choice
```

However, if you wish to generate a custom error, you can inherit from Exception and override `__str__`:

```
class MatrixLenError(Exception):
    pass

matrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
if len(matrix) != len(matrix[0]) and len(set(map(len, matrix))) != 1:
    raise MatrixLenError('The matrix must be square')
```

Comment: `class MatrixLenError(Exception): pass; raise MatrixLenError("The matrix must be square")` shall also work - no need to override `__str__` on later versions.

Comment: It's a nice suggestion but I think OP's asking for the specific logic related to checking if a matrix is squared

Comment: Also, you'd need to compare the length of every row, not just the first.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ good to know about custom errors. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Although your code works, it won't for a matrix such as `[[1,2], [1,2,3]]`.

First of all, encapsulate this logic in a method:

```
def is_squared(matrix):
    # Check that all rows have the correct length, not just the first one
    return all(len(row) == len(matrix) for row in matrix)
```

Then, you can just:

```
inverse = []
matrix = [[1,2], [3,4]]
if not is_squared(matrix):
    raise AttributeError("The matrix must be squared")
```

Comment: Thank u for all your help